# Parsing get(paste0()) objects within dplyr into a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm building a new app in Shiny and it needs to do flexible/reactive aggregated data sets that takes in some inputIDs. I really like dplyr, so I'm using it to create this data sets. But I'm getting an error at parsing the command

> ... %>% summarise( get(paste0(substr(dis,1,4),".mean")) = mean(dis), count = n() )

This is an example of the data set:

```
n=100
taxi <- data.frame(conversion=c(rep(1,20),rep(0,80)),
             day = sample(1:7, n, TRUE),
             hour = sample(0:23,n, TRUE),
             source= sample(1:4, n, TRUE),
             service= sample(1:5, n, TRUE),
             relevancy= sample(1:4, n, TRUE),
             tollfree= sample(c(0,1), n, TRUE),
             distance= sample(0:15, n, TRUE),
             similarity= sample(seq(0,1,0.01), n, TRUE),
             simi.names= sample(c('[0,0.25)','[0.25,0.5)','[0.5,0.75)','[0.75,1]'), n, TRUE),
             dist.names= sample(c('[0,1)','[1,2)','[2,3)','[3,4)','[4,15]'), n, TRUE),
             week= sample(1:7, n, TRUE),
             rel= sample(c(1,4), n, TRUE))
```

and this is how my last attempt looks like: 
**Ui.R**

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("",
               tabPanel("Data",
                        sidebarLayout(
                          sidebarPanel(
                            selectInput("dataset", h5("Choose a dataset:"), choices = c("taxicabs", "liquor stores")),
                            radioButtons("discrete", h5("I want to discretize:"), choices = c("similarity", "distance","similarity & distance","none"),
                                               inline=F, selected = "none"),
                            radioButtons("agg", h5("I want to aggregate:"), choices = c("day in weekdays/weekends", "revelancy in binary revelancy",
                                                                                             "day in weekdays/weekends &  revelancy in binary revelancy","none"),
                                         inline=F, selected = "none"),
                            checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h5("Dataset Features:"), 
                                               choices = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","similarity"), inline = F,
                                               selected = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","similarity"))
                          ),
                          mainPanel(
                            numericInput("obs", label = h5("Number of observations to view"), 10, min = 5, max = 15, step = 1),
                            tableOutput("view") 
                          )
                        )
               ),
               tabPanel("Model",
                        h3("Best logistic model with logit link and variable selection via stepwise AIC "),
                        verbatimTextOutput("model"),
                        h3("MSE"),
                        tableOutput("measures")
               ),
               tabPanel("Graphs",
                        sidebarLayout(
                          sidebarPanel(    
                            selectInput('zcol', 'Variable to be fixed',  names(taxi[,-c(1,4,5,7,8,9,10,11)])),
                            selectInput("levels", "Levels",1:5)
                          ),
                          mainPanel(
                            plotOutput('plot3'),
                            plotOutput('plot1'),
                            plotOutput('plot2')
                          )
                        ))

 ))
```

**Server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
datasetInput <- reactive({
switch(input$dataset,
       "taxicabs" = taxi,
       "liquor stores" = liq)
 })

observe({
if (input$discrete == 'none' & input$agg == 'none') {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","similarity"),
                           inline=F, selected =c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","similarity"))
} else if (input$discrete == 'none' & input$agg == 'day in weekdays/weekends'){
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("week","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","similarity"),
                           inline=F, selected =c("week","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","similarity"))
} else if (input$discrete == 'none' & input$agg == 'revelancy in binary revelancy'){
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("day","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","distance","similarity"),
                           inline=F, selected =c("day","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","distance","similarity"))
} else if (input$discrete == 'none' & input$agg == 'day in weekdays/weekends &  revelancy in binary revelancy'){
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("week","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","distance","similarity"),
                           inline=F, selected =c("week","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","distance","similarity"))
}

  else if(input$discrete == 'similarity' & input$agg == 'none') {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","simi.names"),
                           inline=F, selected = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","simi.names"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'similarity' & input$agg == 'day in weekdays/weekends'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("week","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","simi.names"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("week","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","simi.names"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'similarity' & input$agg == 'revelancy in binary revelancy'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("day","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","distance","simi.names"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("day","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","distance","simi.names"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'similarity' & input$agg == 'day in weekdays/weekends &  revelancy in binary revelancy'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("week","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","distance","simi.names"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("week","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","distance","simi.names"))
  }

  else if(input$discrete == 'distance' & input$agg == 'none') {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","dist.names","similarity"),
                           inline=F, selected =c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","dist.names","similarity"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'distance' & input$agg == 'day in weekdays/weekends'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("week","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","dist.names","similarity"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("week","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","dist.names","similarity"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'distance' & input$agg == 'revelancy in binary revelancy'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("day","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","dist.names","similarity"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("day","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","dist.names","similarity"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'distance' & input$agg == 'day in weekdays/weekends &  revelancy in binary revelancy'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("week","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","dist.names","similarity"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("week","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","dist.names","similarity"))
  }

  else if(input$discrete == 'similarity & distance' & input$agg == 'none') {
  updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","dist.names","simi.names"),
                           inline=F, selected =c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","dist.names","simi.names"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'similarity & distance' & input$agg == 'day in weekdays/weekends'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("week","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","dist.names","simi.names"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("week","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","dist.names","simi.names"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'similarity & distance' & input$agg == 'revelancy in binary revelancy'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("day","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","dist.names","simi.names"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("day","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","dist.names","simi.names"))
  } else if (input$discrete == 'similarity & distance' & input$agg == 'day in weekdays/weekends &  revelancy in binary revelancy'){
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = c("week","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","dist.names","simi.names"),
                             inline=F, selected =c("week","hour","source","service","rel","tollfree","dist.names","simi.names"))
  }
 })

 observe({ 
if(input$discrete == "similarity & distance") {

  #all discrete 
  datasetagg <- reactive({ 
    eval(substitute(right_join(
      datasetInput() %>% select(cg) %>% group_by(cg) %>% summarise(count=n()),
      datasetInput() %>% filter(conversion==1) %>% select(icg) %>% count(cg)
    ) %>% mutate(prop.conv = n/count), 
    list(cg=as.symbol(input$checkGroup))))
  })

} else if(input$discrete == "similarity" | "distance") {

  # one continuous
  datasetagg <- reactive({ 
    eval(substitute(right_join( # the error is in the next line!
      datasetInput() %>% select(cg) %>% group_by(cg[-which(cg == dis)]) %>% summarise(get(paste0(substr(dis,1,4),".mean"))=mean(dis),count=n()),
      datasetInput() %>% filter(conversion==1) %>% select(cg) %>% count(cg[-which(cg == dis)])
    ) %>% mutate(prop.conv = n/count), 
    list(cg=as.symbol(input$checkGroup),
         dis=as.symbol(input$discrete))))
  })

} else if(input$discrete == "none") {

  # two  
  datasetagg <- reactive({ 
    eval(substitute(right_join(
      datasetInput() %>% select(cg) %>% group_by(cg[-which(cg == c('distance','similarity'))]) %>% summarise(dist.mean=mean(distance),simi.mean=mean(similarity),count=n()),
      datasetInput() %>% filter(conversion==1) %>% select(cg) %>% count(cg[-which(cg == c('distance','similarity'))])
    ) %>% mutate(prop.conv = n/count), 
    list(cg=as.symbol(input$checkGroup))))
  })
}
})

# head of the table  
output$view <- renderTable({
head(datasetagg(), n = input$obs)
})


 })
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try putting in dplyr:summarise - I had an issue where it loaded the wrong function

Comment: Doesn't help.. The best I've gotten so far is with the answer below with: `setNames()` but I still get `Error in head(datasetagg(), n = input$obs) : 
  could not find function "datasetagg"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

However, the real issue is that you're trying to use `get(paste0(substr(dis,1,4),".mean"))` as the name of a parameter in summarise. Named parameters in R aren't evaluated, they're just a piece of text.

The code you pasted needed quite extensive rewriting.

1. The first `observe` section at the top was needlessly convoluted - it can be simplified into 4 `if` statements as shown.
2. You can't dynamically define your `reactive`s in the way you did. You need a single `reactive` to be declared with all the conditional logic inside that. It's also much neater to do any necessary processing of the input variables outside of the dplyr code.
3. When you're dynamically defining the columns for `select`, `group_by`, etc., you can use the approach you originally intended using `eval(substitute())`, but it makes for code that's harder to write properly. It's much better, in my opinion, to use the standard evaluation versions of the functions, e.g. `select_` and `group_by_`. For `input$checkgroup`, you need to use the `.dots` parameter (and the `vars` parameter for `count_`).
4. In your original code, you were coercing the `input$checkgroup` variable to a symbol, which only takes the first element of the vector.
5. The way to name the columns dynamically in `summarise_` is to use `setNames` and the `.dots` parameter.

I'm still not sure that some of the output is exactly what you were intending, particularly the proportion column, but this should give you something to build on that works.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(navbarPage("",
                   tabPanel("Data",
                            sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel(
                                selectInput("dataset", h5("Choose a dataset:"), choices = c("taxicabs", "liquor stores")),
                                radioButtons("discrete", h5("I want to discretize:"), choices = c("similarity", "distance","similarity & distance","none"),
                                             inline=F, selected = "none"),
                                radioButtons("agg", h5("I want to aggregate:"), choices = c("day in weekdays/weekends", "relevancy in binary relevancy",
                                                                                            "day in weekdays/weekends &  relevancy in binary relevancy","none"),
                                             inline=F, selected = "none"),
                                checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", label = h5("Dataset Features:"), 
                                                   choices = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","similarity"), inline = F,
                                                   selected = c("day","hour","source","service","relevancy","tollfree","distance","similarity"))
                              ),
                              mainPanel(
                                numericInput("obs", label = h5("Number of observations to view"), 10, min = 5, max = 15, step = 1),
                                tableOutput("view") 
                              )
                            )
                   ),
                   tabPanel("Model",
                            h3("Best logistic model with logit link and variable selection via stepwise AIC "),
                            verbatimTextOutput("model"),
                            h3("MSE"),
                            tableOutput("measures")
                   ),
                   tabPanel("Graphs",
                            sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel(    
                                selectInput("zcol", "Variable to be fixed",  c("hour", "source", "tollfree", "rel")),
                                selectInput("levels", "Levels",1:5)
                              ),
                              mainPanel(
                                plotOutput("plot3"),
                                plotOutput("plot1"),
                                plotOutput("plot2")
                              )
                            ))

))
```

**server.R**

```
library("shiny")
library("dplyr")

n <- 1000
taxi <- data.frame(day = sample(1:7, n, TRUE),
                   hour = sample(0:23,n, TRUE),
                   source= sample(1:4, n, TRUE),
                   service= sample(1:5, n, TRUE),
                   relevancy= sample(1:4, n, TRUE),
                   tollfree= sample(c(0,1), n, TRUE),
                   distance= sample(0:15, n, TRUE),
                   similarity= sample(seq(0,1,0.01), n, TRUE),
                   simi.names= sample(c('[0,0.25)','[0.25,0.5)','[0.5,0.75)','[0.75,1]'), n, TRUE),
                   dist.names= sample(c('[0,1)','[1,2)','[2,3)','[3,4)','[4,15]'), n, TRUE),
                   week= sample(1:7, n, TRUE),
                   rel= sample(c(1,4), n, TRUE),
                   conversion = sample(0:1, n, TRUE))

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "taxicabs" = taxi,
           "liquor stores" = liq)
  })

  observe({
    choices <- c("day", "hour", "source", "service", "relevancy", "tollfree", "distance", "similarity")
    if (grepl("day in weekdays/weekends", input$agg))  {
      choices[1] <- "week"
    }
    if (grepl("relevancy", input$agg))  {
      choices[5] <- "rel"
    }      
    if (grepl("similarity", input$discrete)) {
      choices[8] <- "simi.names"
    }
    if (grepl("distance", input$discrete)) {
      choices[7] <- "dist.names"
    }
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", choices = choices,
                               inline = F, selected = choices)
  })

  datasetagg <- reactive({ 
    cg <- input$checkGroup
    dis <- input$discrete
    cg_not_d_or_s <- cg[!(cg %in% c("distance", "similarity"))]
    if(input$discrete == "similarity & distance") {
      #all discrete 
      right_join(
        datasetInput() %>%
          select_(.dots = cg) %>%
          group_by_(.dots = cg) %>%
          summarise(count=n()),
        datasetInput() %>%
          filter(conversion==1) %>%
          select_(.dots = cg) %>%
          count_(vars = cg)
      ) %>% mutate(prop.conv = n/count)
    } else if(input$discrete %in% c("similarity", "distance")) {
      cg_not_dis <- cg[cg != dis]
        # one continuous
      right_join(
        datasetInput() %>%
          group_by_(.dots = cg_not_dis) %>%
          summarise_(.dots = setNames(c(paste0("mean(", dis, ")"), "n()"),
                                      c(paste0(substr(dis, 1, 4), ".mean"), "count"))) %>%
          select_(.dots = c(cg_not_dis, paste0(substr(dis, 1, 4), ".mean"), "count")),
        datasetInput() %>%
          filter(conversion==1) %>%
          select_(.dots = cg_not_dis) %>%
          count_(vars = cg_not_dis)
      ) %>% mutate(prop.conv = n/count)
    } else if(input$discrete == "none") {
      # two  
      right_join(
        datasetInput() %>%
          select_(.dots = cg) %>%
          group_by_(.dots = cg_not_d_or_s) %>%
          summarise(dist.mean=mean(distance), simi.mean=mean(similarity), count=n()),
        datasetInput() %>%
          filter(conversion==1) %>%
          select_(.dots = cg) %>%
          count_(vars = cg_not_d_or_s)
      ) %>% mutate(prop.conv = n/count)
    }
  })

  # head of the table  
  output$view <- renderTable({
    head(datasetagg(), n = input$obs)
  })

})
```

Comment: I edited and now there is a full code. But I still get Error in `head(datasetagg(), n = input$obs) : could not find function "datasetagg"`

Comment: @GabrielaOlinto your code needs quite extensive rewriting. I've made a start, but it would be much more helpful if you could also provide some sample data for at least `taxi`.

Comment: @GabrielaOlinto could you try to explain in words what sort of output you're expecting? What columns are you intending for the join to be by? `input$checkgroup` potentially has several values. What were you intending to count on the right hand side of the join? What is the conversion column?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to add the column conversion on the fake dataset. But what I want is to have the counts of the factors variables and the means for the continuous variables. The `input$checkgroup` has all variables I want to select (factors and continuous).

Comment: It would be something like this: `right_join(
  taxi %>% select(day ,hour, source , service , relevancy , tollfree, distance, simi.names) %>% group_by(day ,hour, source , service , relevancy , tollfree,  simi.names) %>% summarise(dist.mean=mean(distance),count=n()),
  taxi %>% filter(conversion==1) %>% select(day ,hour, source , service , relevancy , tollfree, distance, simi.names) %>% count(day ,hour, source , service , relevancy , tollfree, simi.names)
) %>% mutate(prop.conv = n/count)`

Comment: Added a rewritten version of your code which works, and hopefully approximates what you were intending.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much! I didn't know most of the things you said. Much neater code. Appreciate!